# Xamarin Forms - grid height does not adjust with label wrapping

Tags: xamarin.forms, grid

I have a grid with a label in it. The label has a text with a length larger than the width of the grid, hence it is wrapped. The grid however does not change its height based on the wrapped text, causing only the first line to be visible. I have set the grid rowheight to Auto.

Any other ideas?

EDIT: the code (a label in a grid)

```
<Grid RowSpacing="20">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label x:Name="This is a label which is wrapped" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" FontSize="16"/>

</Grid>
```

EDIT: image result

[image]

Comment: To get help, show the code you have. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Take a look at the edit I made. I added the code for a label in a grid.

Comment: Is this on Android or iOS? Is the code you show inside a `<ListView.ItemTemplate>`? Or is it inside any other layout (stacklayout, another grid, etc)?

Comment: It's in the cross-platform code, so both. The grid is inside a ContentPage.

Comment: I mean, are you seeing this symptom on both iOS and Android?

Comment: This symptom can be seen on both Android and iOS

Comment: I have create a new sample to test your code and the grid will adjust the label's height.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and it works, my workload is Android11, API30.

```
<Grid RowSpacing="20"> 
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            
        <Label x:Name="label"
               Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In facilisis nulla eu felis fringilla vulputate. Nullam porta eleifend lacinia. Donec at iaculis tellus."
               Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               FontSize="16"/>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I've updated my question with an image, it still does not work for me.

Comment: To be sure: That is the only xaml on that page? Other than being wrapped in `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><ContentPage xmlns=... ... x:Class="...">` ...YOUR_XAML_HERE... `</ContentPage>`